# Automatically delete older duplicate emails in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, rules

Say I receive a bunch of status updates about remote servers in my mailbox, several dozen emails every day.

How do I set up a rule that deletes the oldest IDENTICAL (header and body) email from my Outlook, so that I only have the most recent update? Is this even possible without addons?

Looking forward to your answer.

Comment: I don't have an answer to your exact problem, but I have a couple of different rules set up for these types of status updates. One dumps all alerts for a particular service into a folder, which I then use auto-archive to automatically delete those older than a day. The other automatically deletes the messages that are "OK" in the subject and only lets the ones that are "DOWN" into my mailbox. Depends on how the messages look and how you use them.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what you have tried so far and where you got stuck. We can try to help you from there.